# Why do these SVG images not loading properly when changing source on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, image, blogger, imagesource

I am trying to achieve an effect using HTML and JavaScript to switch between two SVG files on hover, but for some reason when I hover the images do not load correctly, instead showing the default thumbnail as if the files didn't exist. This image tag is included in a pure CSS modal and I am using Blogger. By the way, I am aware I can probably do this using background-image in CSS, but I would really like to do it using this method, since if I learn to do this in Blogger, some other elements could benefit from this code. I am hosting the SVG files on Google Drive.

```
<div id='OrderForm' class='OrderFormWindow'>
    <div id='OrderFormBox'><a href='#CloseOrderForm'><img id='CloseButton' src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=0B72zeCWWNwv9MndXVXRVaTN6ZHM' onmouseover='closebuttonhover(this);' onmouseout='closebuttonunhover(this);'/></a></div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function closebuttonhover(CloseButton) {
    CloseButton.setAttribute('src', 'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=0B72zeCWWNwv9QjdDdm80UFpNemM');
}
function closebuttonunhover(CloseButton) {
    CloseButton.setAttribute('src', 'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=0B72zeCWWNwv9MndXVXRVaTN6ZHM');
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was using the same Google Drive direct link with the &amp code for & in the JavaScript function. Once you change & back to & the link works.